# Progressive Web App (PWA) in Firefox (Android) with Single Sign On (SSO)

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, single-sign-on, progressive-web-apps

My Progressive Web App needs to authenticate with Single Sign On in a different path/domain:

My app path: https://xyz.app.com/app 
SSO server path: https://sso.xyz.app.com/auth

When the standalone PWA is loaded in Google Chrome, when the app redirects to the SSO server path, the browser opens a new window, but when SSO server redirects to the app path again this new window is closed and user is back to the PWA main window.

When the standalone PWA is loaded in Firefox, the browser doesn't recognize when the SSO server redirects to app path again and the new window is not closed. Is this a Firefox bug? Any suggestions of how to do Firefox recognize the app path again and close the opened window?